# onsubmit not working in form tag of partial view

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

I am new in asp.net core and facing one issue. I have a partial view which is updated by Ajax call inside the main view. The calling button is also inside the partial view. Now I want to show a loader image for some fix time when I click the button and then results from ajax call will be loaded. For this I wrote a function to display the image for 5 seconds. But when I am clicking the button image appears and suddenly disappears. Even if I removed setTimeout then also same behavior. Below is the code from partial view. Please advice.

```html
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Parser" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="#CustomerList" onsubmit="return show();">
                    <input type="text" id="txtWeb" name="Web" placeholder="Please enter" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 20px;" />
                    <button type="submit" id="button1">
                        Click
                    </button>
                    <p>
                        @ViewBag.Id
                    </p>

                    <img src="~/img/ajax-loader.gif" id="img" style="display:none" />
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        function show() {
                                                        document.getElementById('img').style.display = 'block';
                            setTimeout(hide, 5000);
                        }

                        function hide() {
                            document.getElementById('img').style.display = 'none';
                        }

                    </script>
                  
                </form>
```

Why the display style of image automatically set to 'none' again here?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If it is solved, please accept it as an answer, otherwise, please tell me your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I am clicking the button image appears and suddenly
> disappears

This is because the `onsubmit` method directly executes **its own process**, which skips other codes in the `show` method.

Here **its own process** of the onsubmit method is to directly submit the form to `/Home/Parser` action.

To make the code in the `show` method execute normally, you need to use the **`event.preventDefault();`** statement to prevent the original process, and then at the end of the `hide` method, manually create the form submission code by ajax.

```
<script>  
    function show() {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('img').style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout(hide, 5000);
    }
    function hide() {
        document.getElementById('img').style.display = 'none';
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Home/Parser",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#txtWeb").val(data);// here is my test code
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

In Home controller:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Parser()
        {
            return Json("new value");
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]